# How do you correctly configure aws-vault to work with Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 with [profile ...]  set in .aws/config and /credentials set up, however am seeing 2 separate errors depending on if I use kwallet or secret-service - neither appears to work as expected, initial error:

```
$ aws-vault --debug ls
2021/02/23 18:35:47 [keyring] Considering backends: [kwallet secret-service file]
2021/02/23 18:35:47 Loading config file /home/leigh/.aws/config
2021/02/23 18:35:47 Parsing config file /home/leigh/.aws/config
aws-vault: error: The name org.kde.kwalletd was not provided by any .service files
```

On a post elsewhere it was recommended to use 'secret-service' as: `export AWS_VAULT_BACKEND=secret-service`

Yet with that setting raises a new error:

```
$ aws-vault --debug ls
2021/02/23 18:40:32 [keyring] Considering backends: [secret-service]
2021/02/23 18:40:32 Loading config file /home/leigh/.aws/config
2021/02/23 18:40:32 Parsing config file /home/leigh/.aws/config
aws-vault: error: The collection "aws-vault" does not exist. Please add a key first
```

What is the correct config to get this to work as expected? Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens if you set `export AWS_VAULT_BACKEND=file` when you run it? I wonder if your config and/or credentials files might have an error?

Comment: Thank you for enquiring, I can’t check any solutions as I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 and aws-vault just worked out of the box for me - not quite a solution to the problem, but did avoid the issue! Thanks